# c Azure получить большой файл и и отправить как ответ частями Spring Boot

Tags: java, файлы, spring-boot, rest, azure

сервиз написанный на Spring через REST запросы передает фалы которые в Azure . По сколку размер файлов стал  слишком большим (0․5- 2 Gb) надо оптимизировать отправку, то есть в место того что скачивать файл а потом перевидать ( ссылку запрошено гарнировать от азур,  причина не известно), нужно передать данные частями которые уже качались ( побитно или более разумное буфероввое решения )

---

Я правильно понимаю это решает мою проблему ( точнее задачу )

```
@GetMapping(value = ROOT + ID)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> download(@PathVariable("fileId") @NotBlank final String fileId) {
        final InputStream content = fileService.getSteam(fileId);
        return streamContent(content);
  
}

 ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamContent(final InputStream stream) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "binary")
                .body(toStreamingResponseBody(stream));
    }
```

Comment: Вы пробовали это реализовать? С чем именно у вас возникли проблемы, сложности? В каком виде Вы хотите получить ответ? Писать все за Вас вряд ли кто-то будет. На данном этапе вопрос мне кажется слишком общим. Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: я не пойму как передать то что еще не скачено , тоесть как из стрима вынуть скачуную часть и передать в другой стрим в спринге

Comment: Выкинуть велосипед, настроить прокси на nginx.

Comment: я за , заказчик нет )